# Memory in C pertaining to pointer arithmetic

Tags: c, pointers, math, heap-memory

I'm currently reading a book on C pointers and there is an example in the book that confuses me:

Suppose we have: `int arr_of_int[] = {5,10,15};`
and we set:      `int *add_of_arr = arr_of_int;`

then I know that the "`add_of_arr`" variable holds the address of: `arr_of_int[0];`
and let's just suppose the address of "`add_of_arr`" is 500.

Now, if I do:    "`add_of_arr += 3;`" then the address of "add_of_arr" is now 512? That's what I'm getting from the book, but shouldn't the address of "`add_of_arr`" still be 500 and only the address HELD by add_of_arr be 512? What i'm getting from the book is that the address of add_of_arr is changing. This confuses me. I'm thinking it's a mistake but I'm not sure.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you caring about the address of an address? Yes, that's well-defined, and yes, there are some cases in which that's even useful, but you're not there yet. In particular, you seem to be talking about `int** add_of_add_of_arr = &add_or_arr` being 500.

Comment: I was confused as to why "&add_of_arr" was changing and not "add_of_arr", but it looks like a typo.

Comment: Reading our assumptions exactly as written, you are right and the book is wrong. Well spotted! Maybe you should get a better, more precise book. Just that: an `int` is not guaranteed to have 4 bytes. It can be any size from 1(!). Also, if the address of `addr` (use better names!) is `500`, the address of `array` cannot be `500`, too, so the value after incrementing cannot be `512` (assuming `sizeof(int) == 4U`)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a typo: address **in** add_of_arr is now 512, but the address **of** add_of_addr has not changed.

Answer (score 0):

You are confounding two things: A pointer is a *variable* to store a memory 
address. As a variable it also has its own address where it resides in memory. As you said, let this be 500. 
The expression `add_of_arr=arr_of_int` hence copies the address of 
`arr_of_int[0]` into memory location 500. Now assume, `arr_of_int` is at 
memory location 400. Then `add_of_arr=arr_of_int` stores 400 into memory location 500. After `add_of_arr += 3` your pointer at memory location 500  contains 412. The *address* of `add_of_arr` (obtained by `&add_of_arr`) however still is 500 but its *value* (obtained by `add_of_arr`) has changed from 400 to 412.

Comment: Looks more like the book's author was confused. OP is correct!